# 好きな動物, 好きな学校, 好きな会社 pitch accent

Tags: pitch-accent

It seems:

- 動物: どうぶつ{LHHH}
- 会社: かいしゃ{LHHH}
- 学校: がっこう{LHHH}

Given that 好き is 尾高, すきな{LHL}, how are 好きな動物, 好きな学校, 好きな会社 pronounced?

I think I hear すきなどうぶつ{LHLHLLL}, not sure if it's that or すきなどうぶつ{LHLLLLL}. What about the other two?

Comment: I'm afraid you are either not hearing it right or not converting what you hear into those bars right. I wouldn't be surprised if the latter was the case because many native speakers are also very poor at it.

Comment: @aguijonazo Then I guess my question is: so they don't change pitch patterns? Is it すきなどうぶつ{LHLLHHH}?

Comment: At normal speed, it would be すきなどうぶつ{LHLLLLL}. Curiously, however, すきなどうぶつ{LHLLHHH} doesn’t sound so artificial as きらいなどうぶつ{LHHHLHHH}. It’s almost always きらいなどうぶつ{LHHHHHHH}. I guess if it ends high, it stays high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, すきなどうぶつ{LHLHLLL} is impossible, that's just an issue with your perception. (How well do you score on [this site](https://kotu.io/tests/pitchAccent/perception/minimalPairs)? It should be 100%.)

As for すきなどうぶつ{LHLLLLL} vs すきなどうぶつ{LHLLHHH}, that's actually not a question of pitch accent, but rather a question of **intonation** (whether you rise back up for a word or not).

In this case, すきなどうぶつ{LHLLLLL} is more natural, but that isn't a general rule: *it depends on the semantic relationship of the modifier and the following word.*

For example, if you have 白い雪が, that is said approximately しろいゆきが{LHLLHL}, because 白い is purely descriptive, it's not selecting one type of snow out of multiple differently colored snow (at least normally...)

But if you are looking at a field of flowers and you want to say something about the blue ones in particular, you would say 青い花は, that is said closer to あおいはなは{LHLLLLL} (i.e., you don't raise back up for 花, despite it having an accent on な.)

However, *big note*, the HL notation is totally insufficient for notating  phrases and is omitting detail even in this very answer, because when considering intonation for multiple accents, each accent is said at a different height, so in reality you would need to use a more expressive notation (like a graph, or honestly just an audio file).

Comment: I don't know if the test you linked has an end to it, like 1000 questions, but I did it twice both 100% at 150 something pairs. In more general terms, I do have a problem with sound perception inasmuch as I'm musically tone weak and congenitally language challenged/impaired. Language acquisition happened much later in life to me comparing to other kids, and I have always had a problem with enunciation (in any language I speak). But I guess I've been doing Japanese long enough to not have issues hearing pitch accent in isolation and can tell if something diverts from the most popular form.

Comment: @EddieKal Great. Maybe next time do a quick recording of these cases, which would allow the answerer to give some explanation of why you may have misheard (or why the sample is weird/dialect/etc).